# Meteor: How to insert a set of documents into a collection upon user creation

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my application, I have an Ingredients collection. Users can join and create their own ingredients which have a 'createdBy' attribute so that they can only view their own ingredients from the collection.

What I want to do is provide a set of about 100 ingredients that are already there when the user first joins so every user who joins has their own default set of predefined ingredients which they can then edit etc.

So I am guessing I need to insert this predefined set of ingredients when a user first joins, and have the 'createdBy' set with the new users ID. How can I achieve this?

Should I just call a method from Accounts.onCreateUser() or is there another way?

Comment: Could you instead have an isPublic Ingredient attribute that doesn't require a createdBy?  This may or may not be helpful depending on how you're using the data.

Comment: This wouldn't be suitable as each user should be able to modify the set of ingredients according to their own specific needs. The ingredients can't be shared among all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing an insert in Accounts.onCreateUser() sounds like a viable option to me.